# Exception while exporting database using MLCP

Tags: marklogic, mlcp

I am trying to export Database using MLCP But I am getting exception `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`

**MLCP Command**

```
mlcp export -host localhost -port 8011 -username admin -password admin -mode local -output_file_path C:\test_sample -output_type archive
```

**Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.preProcessForWindows(GenericOptionsParser.java:438)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.parseGeneralOptions(GenericOptionsParser.java:484)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.<init>(GenericOptionsParser.java:170)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.<init>(GenericOptionsParser.java:153)
        at com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump.runCommand(ContentPump.java:120)
        at com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump.main(ContentPump.java:74)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 3, length 2
        at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3319)
        at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1874)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:49)
        ... 6 more
```

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: I just ran your command locally using MLCP 10.0.7 and it worked fine. What version of MLCP are you using?

Comment: And what version of Java (I ran with Java 8) - I have seen other libraries with a similar error when using Java version greater than 8, so there may be an issue with underlying dependency.

Comment: MLCP Version is 10.0.4

Comment: Some libraries when attempting to determine the Java version expected `1.8` and in later versions of Java there is no point release, just a whole number i.e. `11` https://github.com/OpenIdentityPlatform/commons/issues/4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue that has been reported https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-contentpump/issues/169

It seems that the version of the Hadoop library dependency needs to be updated.