# Getting Java string index range exception in MLCP import

Tags: java, marklogic

I am trying to import a file into MarkLogic database using mlcp command.
And I am getting a java string exception in return.

I am running the mlcp-10.0.9 on windows 11 which has the java version:
java 19 2022-09-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 19+36-2238)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19+36-2238, mixed mode, sharing)

Here is my mlcp command I am using

`mlcp.bat -options_file mlcp_config.txt`

And here is the error I am getting in return -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.preProcessForWindows(GenericOptionsParser.java:440)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.parseGeneralOptions(GenericOptionsParser.java:486)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.<init>(GenericOptionsParser.java:170)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.<init>(GenericOptionsParser.java:153)
        at com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump.runCommand(ContentPump.java:120)
        at com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump.main(ContentPump.java:74)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: Range [0, 3) out of bounds for length 2
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$1.apply(Preconditions.java:55)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$1.apply(Preconditions.java:52)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$4.apply(Preconditions.java:213)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$4.apply(Preconditions.java:210)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:98)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckFromToIndex(Preconditions.java:112)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkFromToIndex(Preconditions.java:349)
        at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:4602)
        at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:2715)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:51)
```

Please suggest on what might be going wrong.

Comment: I believe you should remove special character like double quote " in your file

Comment: Thanks for your comment, But I am not using any quotes anywhere in the mlcp config file or anywhere in the command. Is it something to do with the java installation in windows 11. As I was having no issue in running mlcp in windows 10 with same set up but with different java version though. Currently using JDK19.

Comment: https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-contentpump/issues/169

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68861729/14419 this issue will be addressed in MLCP 11